# Print iota-like symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to print the following iota-like symbol:

[image]

It is not available in the standard special characters. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Unicode](https://unicode.org) [codepoint 1D7C](https://codepoints.net/U+1D7C) "latin small letter iota with stroke":

```
"\:1D7C"
(*    ᵼ    *)

% // ToCharacterCode
(*    {7548}    *)
```